# Valor recibido como undefined

Tags: javascript

tengo un listado de presupuestos con unos botones que al pulsarlos muestra 2 campos que estaban ocultos y al pulsar otro botón de aceptar llama a una función que guarda ambos campos y otros valores en un archivo PHP. Pues bien, tengo el problema de que las variables fecha_recog y fecha_entreg las recibo como undefined, ¿Sabeis por que?

Listado:

```
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptar_<?=$id?>" onclick="mostrarInputval(<?=$id?>)">Aceptar</button>
              <br>
              <label id="Fecha_recogidalabel_<?=$id?>" style="display:none">Fecha de recogida del material: </label>
              <input type="date" name="Fecha_recogida_<?=$id?>" min="<?php echo $fecha_manana ?>" id="Fecha_recogida_<?=$id?>" style="display:none">
              <br>
              <label id="Fecha_propuestalabel_<?=$id?>" style="display:none">Fecha propuesta de devolución del material: </label>
              <input type="date" name="Fecha_propuesta_<?=$id?>" min="<?php echo $fecha_pasado ?>" id="Fecha_propuesta_<?=$id?>" style="display:none">
              <br>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptacion_<?=$id?>" onclick="guardarAceptacion(<?=$id?>)" style="display:none">Aceptar</button>
              </td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="botonRechazar_<?=$id?>">Rechazar y Cancelar</button></td>
```

Función que guarda la aceptación:

```
function guardarAceptacion(idTrab){
  var fecha_recog = document.getElementById['Fecha_recogida_' + idTrab];
  var fecha_entreg = document.getElementById['Fecha_propuesta_' + idTrab];
  var ventana = confirm("¿Aceptar Presupuesto y fechas de entrega? "+fecha_recog);
if (ventana === true) {
$.post("procesarAceptado.php", {
    fecha_recogida: fecha_recog,
    fecha_devolucion: fecha_entreg,
    id_parte: idTrab,
  },
  function(mostrar) {
    alert("Guardado correctamente!");
    location.reload(true);
  });
}

}
```

Comment: `getElementById` se usa con paréntesis, no con corchetes. Prueba así: **`var fecha_recog = document.getElementById('Fecha_recogida_' + idTrab);`** y también: **`var fecha_entreg = document.getElementById('Fecha_propuesta_' + idTrab);`**

Comment: Acabo de cambiar mi respuesta en la otra pregunta que hicistes, no me di cuenta que tenias ese typo y lo reproduje en mi respuesta (ahora arreglada tambien), gracias @A.Cedano por el aporte

Comment: Veo que luego quieres usar esos datos recogidos con `getElementById` como texto plano, por lo tanto les tienes que poner un `.value` al final, sino no te funcionará porque tal como lo tienes ahora recuperas el objeto completo, no su valor suelto. Es decir, debes usar esta sintaxis:  **`document.getElementById('Fecha_recogida_' + idTrab).value`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es que debes usar paréntesis en `getElementById()`, en cambio, estás usando corchetes. [Revisa atentamente la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Ahora bien, en tu código hay varias malas prácticas:

- Deberías evitar el uso de funciones *in-line*. Es decir, puestas en el código HTML. No hay separación de responsabilidades, y el código es difícil de mantener. Si tienes miles de funciones dispersas en tus archivos HTML y hay que cambiar algo de esas funciones, te quiero ver hurgando entre cientos o miles de archivos para ver dónde pusiste esas funciones.
- Deberías evitar igualmente poner reglas de estilo (CSS) *in-line*, por el mismo motivo. Es mejor usar clases y aplicar los estilos en esas clases. En la respuesta no me voy a meter con eso, dejaré tu CSS *in-line* aunque sea una pésima práctica, porque no es el problema principal que nos atañe, pero **considera corregir esto en tu código final**.
- Ambas cosas, además, permiten re-utilizar código. Y permiten que escribas un código más limpio y menos repetitivo.

Aplicando lo que dijimos más arriba, podemos llegar a una simplificación del código **usando la lógica**. Por ejemplo, en tu código se ve que:

- **<kbd>a</kbd>** Quieres escuchar los clicks de **un botón que está en un `td`**
- **<kbd>b</kbd>** Quieres obtener el valor de **dos `input` que están en la columna anterior al botón**.

Pues bien, Javascript tiene métodos para alcanzar elementos en un orden lógico (el elemento previo, el o los elemento(s) del tipo `X` de ese elemento previo, etc). Tú puedes escribir un código que siga esa lógica para alcanzar los elementos. Así evitas tener que poner una función *in-line* en caaada elemento para desde ella pasar el id o el valor de ese elemento. Igualmente, evitas tener que poner ids secuenciales en los elementos, a no ser que realmente necesites identificar cada uno para algo en concreto que no puedas resolver de otro modo, pues para lo que quieres hacer aquí **no necesitas asignar ids secuenciales**.

Veamos un ejemplo donde aplicaremos la lógica descrita más arriba en <kbd>a</kbd> y en <kbd>b</kbd>. He agregado otra fila, para que veas que el código funciona igual para todas las filas. Comprobarás que en cada caso el código obtendrá lo que quieres. Es importante comprender esto, porque en Javascript puedes alcanzar los elementos que están organizados de este modo, sin demasiadas complicaciones.

Otra gran ventaja de esto es que si mañana tu código evoluciona, y metes otro `input` (o cualquier otro elemento en tu tabla), podrás alcanzar ese elemento agregando dos líneas a tu código Javascript, sin más historias, alcanzando el elemento del tipo tal, que está en la posición tal.

#### Con Javascript puro

```js
/*
   He agregado una clase btn-guardar a los botones Rechazar y Cancelar para escuchar los
   clicks de cualquiera de ellos en este bloque
   sacando la función in-line de los mismos
*/
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-guardar");
allButtons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    /*
     Referencia a la celda previa al botón
     sobre el cual se hizo click
  */
    var previousCell = e.target.parentNode.previousElementSibling;
    
    /*
      Alcanzamos todos los input de esa celda
    */
    var allInputs = previousCell.querySelectorAll('input');

    /*
      Alcanzamos el primer input de la celda previa
      Usamos aquí índice 0 será el 1er input
    */
    var fechaRecogida = allInputs[0].getAttribute('value');

    /*
      Alcanzamos el segundo input de la celda previa
      Usamos aquí índice 1 será el 2do input
    */
    var fechaEntrega = allInputs[1].getAttribute('value');

    /*
      Aquí están los valores, ahora puedes 
      pasarlos a $.post o hacer lo que quieras
    */
    console.log(`Fecha recogida: ${fechaRecogida}`);
    console.log(`Fecha entrega: ${fechaEntrega}`);

  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptar1">Aceptar</button>
      <br>
      <label style="display:none">Fecha de recogida del material: </label>
      <input type="date" name="Fecha_recogida_1" min="1" id="Fecha_recogida_1" value="1" style="display:none">
      <br>
      <label style="display:none">Fecha propuesta de devolución del material: </label>
      <input type="date" name="Fecha_propuesta_1" min="1" id="Fecha_propuesta_1" value="1A" style="display:none">
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptacion_1" style="display:none">Aceptar</button>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-guardar">Rechazar y Cancelar</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptar2">Aceptar</button>
      <br>
      <label style="display:none">Fecha de recogida del material: </label>
      <input type="date" name="Fecha_recogida_2" min="1" id="Fecha_recogida_2" value="2" style="display:none">
      <br>
      <label style="display:none">Fecha propuesta de devolución del material: </label>
      <input type="date" name="Fecha_propuesta_2" min="1" id="Fecha_propuesta_1" value="2A" style="display:none">
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptacion_2" style="display:none">Aceptar</button>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-guardar">Rechazar y Cancelar</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptacion_1" style="display:none">Aceptar*</button>
```

---

#### Lo mismo, pero usando jQuery

> Lo pongo también en jQuery porque veo que usas jQuery para tu petición `$.post`. Para todos los efectos tú puedes usar la versión en Javascript puro, y puedes mezclar JS puro y jQuery, no hay ningún problema, jQuery no es otra cosa que una librería en JS, cuyo uso relentiza un poco más el código. Sea como sea, mientras menos dependiente seas de librerías mejor, de hecho [*You might not need jQuery* (*Es posible que no necesites jQuery*)](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
/*
   He agregado una clase btn-guardar a los botones Rechazar y Cancelar para escuchar los
   clicks de cualquiera de ellos en este bloque
   sacando la función in-line de los mismos
*/
$(".btn-guardar").on('click', function(e) {
  /*
     Referencia a la celda previa al botón
     sobre el cual se hizo click
  */
  var previousCell = $(this).closest('td').prev();
  
  /*
    Alcanzamos el primer input de la celda previa
    Usamos eq(), aquí 0 será el 1er input
  */
  var fechaRecogida = previousCell.find("input").eq(0).attr('value');

  /*
    Alcanzamos el segundo input de la celda previa
    Usamos eq(), aquí 1 será el 2do input
  */
  var fechaEntrega = previousCell.find("input").eq(1).attr('value');
  
  /*
    Aquí están los valores, ahora puedes 
    pasarlos a $.post o hacer lo que quieras
  */
  console.log(`Fecha recogida: ${fechaRecogida}`);
  console.log(`Fecha entrega: ${fechaEntrega}`);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptar1">Aceptar</button>
      <br>
      <label style="display:none">Fecha de recogida del material: </label>
      <input type="date" name="Fecha_recogida_1" min="1" id="Fecha_recogida_1" value="1" style="display:none">
      <br>
      <label style="display:none">Fecha propuesta de devolución del material: </label>
      <input type="date" name="Fecha_propuesta_1" min="1" id="Fecha_propuesta_1" value="1A" style="display:none">
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptacion_1" style="display:none">Aceptar</button>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-guardar">Rechazar y Cancelar</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptar2">Aceptar</button>
      <br>
      <label style="display:none">Fecha de recogida del material: </label>
      <input type="date" name="Fecha_recogida_2" min="1" id="Fecha_recogida_2" value="2" style="display:none">
      <br>
      <label style="display:none">Fecha propuesta de devolución del material: </label>
      <input type="date" name="Fecha_propuesta_2" min="1" id="Fecha_propuesta_1" value="2A" style="display:none">
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptacion_2" style="display:none">Aceptar</button>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-guardar">Rechazar y Cancelar</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonAceptacion_1" style="display:none">Aceptar*</button>
```